# How could a vote be removed without editing the post?

Tags: support, voting

I downvoted an answer. I could see this:

[image]
A few hours ago it was still there:

[image]
Now, if I check out that answer I can see:

[image]
There is no edit on it. The downvote could've been removed within 5 min after, I would see it. The only possibility is that the downvoter got his account removed?

Comment: Another vote was removed. Either because someone had removed their vote within the time limit, or because the account that voted has been deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why can't we find it on timeline https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49865270/timeline

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: because invalidated or retracted votes are never shown on a timeline.

Comment: @Vega: there could have been multiple users too. Voting is anonymous, and you can remove your vote in a small time window. It'd be a coincidence if this concerned two different users, so its more likely to be a removed account, but still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is not a bug? I mean I feel like adding all details to timeline is good.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: no, it is not a bug. **Voting is anonymous**, we do not expose detailed info on votes in the timeline for that reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The downvote was caused by a spam flag, which casts one automatically from the Community user when the flag is cast. It was retracted automatically when the spam flag was declined.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are two main reasons a vote could be removed without edits after the initial 5 minutes:

1. Serial voting reversal

   If someone was serial voting, the automated script would've reverted the vote, and this wouldn't be visible.
2. Account deletion

   If someone were to delete their account after casting the vote, and their account wouldn't have enough impact to preserve the votes, the votes would have been reverted.

Both of these reasons don't occur often, but one still might have occurred.

Comment: @Vega: no, because serial voting is against multiple posts, in a short time.